# nested HashMap not working properly

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

I am declaring HashMap inside HashMap but it take duplicate value for all key why i am not getting

and this problem solve when i declare link inside loop
My code...

```
public static void setM(){

    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> response = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String,String> link = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        link.put("save_pont", "i"+i);
        response.put(i+"",link);// error here for putting same value for all key
        System.out.println("response ->   "+response);

    }

}
```

Output i am getting ......

```
response ->   {0={save_pont=i0}}
response ->   {1={save_pont=i1}, 0={save_pont=i1}}
response ->   {2={save_pont=i2}, 1={save_pont=i2}, 0={save_pont=i2}}
response ->   {3={save_pont=i3}, 2={save_pont=i3}, 1={save_pont=i3}, 0={save_pont=i3}}
response ->   {3={save_pont=i4}, 2={save_pont=i4}, 1={save_pont=i4}, 0={save_pont=i4}, 4={save_pont=i4}}
response ->   {3={save_pont=i5}, 2={save_pont=i5}, 1={save_pont=i5}, 0={save_pont=i5}, 5={save_pont=i5}, 4={save_pont=i5}}
```

but i need output like ..

```
response ->   {0={save_pont=i0}}
response ->   {1={save_pont=i1}, 0={save_pont=i0}}
response ->   {2={save_pont=i2}, 1={save_pont=i1}, 0={save_pont=i0}}
response ->   {3={save_pont=i3}, 2={save_pont=i2}, 1={save_pont=i1}, 0={save_pont=i0}}
response ->   {3={save_pont=i3}, 2={save_pont=i2}, 1={save_pont=i1}, 0={save_pont=i0}, 4={save_pont=i4}}
response ->   {3={save_pont=i3}, 2={save_pont=i2}, 1={save_pont=i1}, 0={save_pont=i0}, 5={save_pont=i5}, 4={save_pont=i4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the key "save_pont" twice:

```
link.put("save_pont", "i"+i);
```

Thus erasing the previous entry. I think what you want is to put the nested HashMap construction inside the loop.

Comment: i know this will erase link but i am getting wrong output for response variable

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same hashmap and just overwriting the values.
  Declare the hashmap inside for loop as shown below

```
 public static void setM(){

        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> response = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            HashMap<String,String> link = new HashMap<String,String>();
             link.put("save_pont", "i"+i);
            response.put(i+"",link);
            System.out.println("response ->   "+response);

        }

    }
```

Comment: i know this is alternative but link is create every true condition

Comment: @Rishi : Share your complete code so that it will be easy to analyse

Comment: This is my full code with getting and expecting output

Comment: @Rishi : You have to create a new hashmap. For the o/p you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

the `link` object changes every loop iteration. this may help you:

```
public static void setM(){

    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> response = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();

    HashMap<String,String>[] links = new HashMap<String,String>[6];

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        links[i] = new HashMap<String,String>();    
        links[i].put("save_pont", "i"+i);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        HashMap<String,String> link = new HashMap<String,String>();
        response.put(i+"",links[i]);
        System.out.println("response ->   "+response);   
    }    
}
```

Comment: but i don't wanna create link every true condition